# Uploading multiple images in webservice using PHP

Tags: php, android, web-services, file-upload

I am new to webservice using PHP for Android device. I need to work on multiple image upload concept. Please suggest. I have implemented single upload concept the code for single file upload is given below.

```
$data = $_REQUEST;
if($data["prop_images"]){       
            $filename = md5(time()).'.jpg';
            $base=$data["prop_images"];
            $binary = base64_decode($base);         
            $pathtoupload = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_clinchproperties/galupload/';
            //header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');  // binary, utf-8 bytes
            $actual_image_name = time().".jpg";
            $image = $filename;
            $file = fopen($pathtoupload.$filename,  'wb');
            fwrite($file, $binary);
            fclose($file);
        }
```

I need code to upload n number of images at same time. Can any one help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to upload 4 or 5 files in same time?explain

Comment: yes I need n number of files to be uploaded at same time

Comment: write upload code in while loop if you fetch $data from db

Comment: @user3386779 is there any website where we can check the file upload from browser? because I need to check how I receive the data from user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass array of files. As you mentioned in comment, you are sending file data in base64 format, try following code for `PHP`.

**PHP**

```
  $data = $_REQUEST;
  if($data["prop_images"]){ 
    foreach($data["prop_images"] as $img){ //array of images. So loop for every images
        $filename = md5(time()).'.jpg';
        $base=$img;
        $binary = base64_decode($base);         
        $pathtoupload = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_clinchproperties/galupload/';
        $actual_image_name = time().".jpg";
        $image = $filename;
        $file = fopen($pathtoupload.$filename,  'wb');
        fwrite($file, $binary);
        fclose($file);
    }
  }
```

**In android code, make sure to add `[]` in parameter name while making POST request**.
That parameter should be `prop_images[]` as per example I given above.

I'm not an Android developer, but I can post code from our Android developer.

**Android**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://webserver.com/path/to/webservice.php");

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++) {
    //convert your images to base64 and store in base64ImageData.
    reqEntity.addPart("prop_images[]", base64ImageData);   //adding parameter
}

//execute request.
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to check your web service

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="audioupload.php">
 <input type="file" name="file1" multiple>
 <input type="submit"  value="OK">
</form>

audio.php
 <?php  
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"],"audio/".$_FILES["file1"]["name"]);   
  $url = "audio/".$_FILES["file1"]["name"];
  ?>
```

likewise developer can call this service n times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am getting the file is base64 encryption method I have tried using foreach loop but it is not getting the files

Comment: Not an argument! Just for your information, as you mentioned `file1` parameter as `multiple`. It will be an array so, `move_uploaded_file()` doesn't work as the way you demonstrated.