# how to upload multiple image in amazon webservice s3 (Android) same time?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, image-upload

Actually i need to upload multiple image same time in amazon s3 server.   Here is my Single File upload code here::

```
TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
                "selfiesharedev",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                mini_image_path,    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                file,        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
                CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead
        );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple images in webservice using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834733/uploading-multiple-images-in-webservice-using-php)

Comment: finally I got Solution for multiupload android .am using this method https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-s3-transfermanager-batched-file-uploads/

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62610546/8244632) is what I've done to upload or download mutliple files concurrently. It's the complete code in Kotlin, may it help others who'll come here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check this out !

```
  TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(myCredentials);

    ObjectMetadataProvider metadataProvider = new ObjectMetadataProvider() {
        void provideObjectMetadata(File file, ObjectMetadata metadata) {
            // If this file is a JPEG, then parse some additional info
            // from the EXIF metadata to store in the object metadata
            if (isJPEG(file)) {
                metadata.addUserMetadata("original-image-date", 
                                         parseExifImageDate(file));
            }
        }
    }

    MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadFileList(
            myBucket, myKeyPrefix, rootDirectory, fileList, metadataProvider);
```

Comment: TransferManager and MultipleFileUpload are deprecated in java

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3TransferUtility to achieve that.
A sample can be found in:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample

It's also good to read...
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3TransferUtilitySample/S3TransferUtilityTutorial.md
... to understand the code in the sample.

Comment: thankz yaar. finally I got Solution for multiupload android .am using this method https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-s3-transfermanager-batched-file-uploads/