# Amazon s3 upload multiple files android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Incase anyone still looking for a solution i ended up using a loop on the code blew i did not find an official api to do multiple files upload.

**-------**

I have an ArrayList of ImageFiles, that I want to upload to Amazon s3. Their doc provides this code:

```
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);               
transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getContext());
observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

    }
});
observer = transferUtility.upload("buket name", upload_file.getNew_name(),
                                   new File(upload_file.getFile_path()));
```

But this code only takes one file. How can i upload multiple files at once? And if they do not allow this so user can make more requests , what the alternative to do this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I'm late to answer but it will help others who'll come here looking for an answer.

Currently, the only option to upload multiple files is to use a loop passing the files from list as individual file but here's what I found last night and implemented it. I've tested it many times so far.

Advantage of this method is it runs concurrently for every file and not wait for every file to upload or download first to operate on the next file.

It's what I found [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/505#issuecomment-612187402) but I've modified it a little bit for my use in Kotlin.

- First, Create a class, I've named it `MultiUploaderS3` -

  ```
   import android.content.Context
   import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferListener
   import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferState
   import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility
   import io.reactivex.Completable
   import io.reactivex.Observable
   import io.reactivex.Single
   import java.io.File

   class MultiUploaderS3 {

       private fun transferUtility(context: Context): Single<TransferUtility?>? {
           return Single.create { emitter ->
               emitter.onSuccess(
               TransferUtility(s3ClientInitialization(context), context)
               )
           }
       }

       fun uploadMultiple(fileToKeyUploads: Map<File, String>, context: Context): Completable? {
           return transferUtility(context)!!
               .flatMapCompletable { transferUtility ->
                   Observable.fromIterable(fileToKeyUploads.entries)
                       .flatMapCompletable { entry ->
                           uploadSingle(
                               transferUtility,
                               entry.key,
                               entry.value
                           )
                       }
               }
       }

           private fun uploadSingle(
           transferUtility: TransferUtility,
           aLocalFile: File?,
           toRemoteKey: String?
       ): Completable? {
           return Completable.create { emitter ->
               transferUtility.upload(bucketName,toRemoteKey, aLocalFile)
                   .setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {
                       override fun onStateChanged(
                           id: Int,
                           state: TransferState
                       ) {
                           if (TransferState.FAILED == state) {
                               emitter.onError(Exception("Transfer state was FAILED."))
                           } else if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
                               emitter.onComplete()
                           }
                       }

                       override fun onProgressChanged(
                           id: Int,
                           bytesCurrent: Long,
                           bytesTotal: Long
                       ) {
                       }

                       override fun onError(id: Int, exception: Exception) {
                           emitter.onError(exception)
                       }
                   })
           }
       }

   }
  ```
- I've created a function for returning S3Client which is as follows -

  ```
  fun s3ClientInitialization(context: Context): AmazonS3 {
      val cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
          context,
          your key,
          region
      )
      return AmazonS3Client(
          cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider,
          Region.getRegion(Regions.YOUR_REGION)
      )
  }
  ```
- Then, Call it as -

  ```
   val map: Map<File, String> = yourArrayList.map {it to Your_Key_For_Each_File}.toMap()
   MultiUploaderS3().uploadMultiple(map, this)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .subscribe {
           runOnUiThread {
               Toast(this@AddActivity, "Uploading completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }
        }
  ```

I've shared the complete working code, you can change it as you need. You can use the above `MultiUploaderS3` class in the same class as well which will obviously make things easier to access the `TransferListener`.

For Downloading, change the

`transferUtility.upload(bucketName,toRemoteKey, aLocalFile)` in `uploadSingle()`

to

`transferUtility.download(bucketName, fromRemoteKey, aLocalFile)`

and Call it as

`val map: Map<File, String> = yourKeysArrayList.map {Your_FILE_For_Each_KEY to it}.toMap()`

What this will do is it will pass a map of Local file path to Keys.

I have tried uploading 10 files in a single run many times and it takes around 4-5 seconds to upload all of them, it also depends on your internet connection though. I hope the downloading part will work as well. Ask me if there's something or check my [Github](https://github.com/Fauzdar1/MultiUploaderS3) for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create observable for this task

```
 public Observable<AWSFile> upload(List<String> paths) {
        List<Observable<AWSFile>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String path: paths) {
            list.add(upload(path));
        }
        return Observable.concat(list);
    }

public Observable<AWSFile> upload(String filePath) {
        if (filePath == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadWithTransferUtility: ");
            return Observable.never();
        }
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            TransferObserver observer = awsUtil.getTransferUtility(context).upload(awsUtil.getAwsConstants().BUCKET_NAME, file);
            observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    stateChanged(id, state);
                    emitter.onNext(new AWSFile(id,state,file.getName()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                    progressChanged(id, bytesCurrent, bytesTotal);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    error(id,ex);
                    emitter.onError(ex);
                }
            });
            emitter.setCancellable(observer::cleanTransferListener);
        });
}
```

This is just only snippet and you can use it to many files or only one.

EDIT: 
AWSFile.java

```
public class AWSFile {
    private int id;
    private TransferState newState;
    private String filename;
}
```

Comment: What class is AWSFile?

Comment: This is wrapper class to emmit more info about state of file.

Comment: @PiotrBadura subscribed to returned `Observable<AWSFile>` from `upload(List)` method and it only calls `onNext()` once although i have many items in there, what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: Needed to call `onComplete()` with `onNext()`

Comment: Incase you come across this answer, subscribe on thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the uploading code to a method and pass it the file path.
Then you can loop that method on file paths list. At least that's how I did it. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: But this is not the right way to upload multiple images, It should be automated without using any loop.

Answer (score 0):

@Lalit-Fauzdar answer and the mentioned reference is the way to go about it. I am sharing a slight upgrade to the implementation

```
class MultiUploaderS3Client(bucketName:String) {

    var bucketName = bucketName

    fun uploadMultiple(fileToKeyUploads: MutableMap<String,File>, transferUtility: TransferUtility): Completable? {
        return transferUtility(transferUtility)
            .flatMapCompletable { transferUtility ->
                Observable.fromIterable(fileToKeyUploads.entries)
                    .flatMapCompletable { entry ->
                        uploadSingle(
                            transferUtility,
                            entry.value,
                            entry.key
                        )
                    }
            }
    }

    private fun transferUtility(transferUtility: TransferUtility): Single<TransferUtility?> {
        return Single.create { emitter ->
            emitter.onSuccess(
                transferUtility
            )
        }
    }

    private fun uploadSingle(
        transferUtility: TransferUtility?,
        aLocalFile: File?,
        toRemoteKey: String?
    ): Completable? {
        return Completable.create { emitter ->
            transferUtility?.upload(bucketName,toRemoteKey, aLocalFile)
                ?.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {
                    override fun onStateChanged(
                        id: Int,
                        state: TransferState
                    ) {
                        if (TransferState.FAILED == state) {
                            emitter.onError(Exception("Transfer state was FAILED."))
                        } else if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
                            emitter.onComplete()
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onProgressChanged(
                        id: Int,
                        bytesCurrent: Long,
                        bytesTotal: Long
                    ) {
                    }

                    override fun onError(id: Int, exception: Exception) {
                        emitter.onError(exception)
                    }
                })
        }
    }

}
```

> `val multiUploadHashMap = mutableMapOf<String,File>()`

```
MultiUploaderS3Client(AWSConfig.misTicketFilesBucketName).uploadMultiple(multiUploadHashMap, transferUtility)
                        ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        ?.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        ?.subscribe {
                            //Called when all files uploaded
                            Runnable { callback.onComplete(_Result.Success<String>("uploaded successfully")) }
                            handler.post(returnCallback)
                        }
```